# Could this XSS protection with HttpOnly Cookies work?

Tags: security, cookies, xmlhttprequest, httponly

I have done some research on HttpOnly cookies and the problem that exist with the possibility to use an XHR request in combination with the TRACE method to get the cookie value echoed back from the server.

For a secure webapplication I currently have the following setup:

- Session cookie is sent at login with secure and httpOnly properties set
- The TRACE http method is disabled for the complete domain (returning "405 Method not allowed")

To avoid cross site request forgery I have added a random key in a hidden field to the forms. This key is must be returned in each POST request for the request to be accepted.

Apart from this all HTML is escaped by default using whitelisting to select tags and attributes that are allowed, but to illustrate why this is not enough: We previously allowed the style-attribute on span to be used (to color text for example), which could be used to pass javascript in Internet Explorer in the following way:

```
<span style="width: expression(alert('Example'));"> </span>
```

And then to the final question: Could anybody point out any flaws or suggestions to possible flaws in this setup? Or are you using the same or completely different approaches?

Known problems:

- Not all browsers support httpOnly
- Filtering css JS-expressions is not enough, @import(external-style-sheet)  could also work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your post (title a bit misleading) I assume you understand that Httponly attribute prevents access to cookie via document.cookie and does nothing else to protect against the other nasty things that XSS allows including impersonating user (i.e., don't need to steal cookies and can use retrieved CSRF token), checking for vulnerable plugins on browser to install malware, installing javascript key logger, scanning your internal network, etc, rewriting the page, etc.

As you say whitelisting tags and attributes for each  tag is not enough. You have to apply stricter validation on attribute values probably via whitelist regex.

An incomplete list of other things to consider a couple of which are not directly related to XSS or CSRF:

- How do you deal with incomplete html such as missing closing tags?
- How do you handle single quote, double quote, and backslash in user input?
- How do you handle user input that is output in different contexts - such as in url links, attribute values, etc.?

  Do you check that input actually matches input charset encoding?

  Do you explicitly set Content-Type in response header and in meta tag?

  For moderately sensitive user pages served over HTTP if any do you set appropriate Cache-Control header?

  How do you ensure user input is sandboxed? Specifically, if you allow CSS, how do you ensure style is applied only to restricted region and cannot alter other regions?

  Do you have 3rd party javascript including ads on the site?

  Is the session cookie protected against tampering if it should be?

  Do you sanitize all input including HTTP headers that can be modified by user?

  Is the CSRF token truly random - if yes, how do you generate random token? If not, how do you construct it?

  Do you use prepared statements and bind parameters?

  Can users upload files?

  Do you serve user uploaded content such as images, etc? If yes how do you validate file content (GIFAR flaw) and is the file served from same domain?

  Do you provide API access and if yes is it hosted on same domain? What crossdomain restriction do you have?

Comment: Nice list! Most of it is what we've already implemented, charset issues are high on our general testing-list. Are you aware of any sort of whitelist of attribute values considered safe? Because as explained we considered "style" to be safe for a short time which actually isn't safe at all. An overview of properties and validation regexps would be a great source for a lot of webdevelopers.

Comment: We have allowed tags and CSS selectors, allowed attributes for *each* tag and allowed values for *each* of these attributes/selectors based on spec (e.g., color and font-size have different whitelist regex) and our *comfort* level (may allow href only to certain domains). The regex is applied after we walk through each character of input with a library such as icu or iconv and a custom html parser - certain characters are transformed to escaped/htmlentity encoded values. Finally we output only input we understand. Unfortunately the source is not in open source land yet.

Answer (score 2):

HttpOnly Cookies is a good security measure,  but it is not designed to stop XSS,  just make it more difficult for attackers to exploit xss vulnerabilities.   Let me elaborate.

A token based xsrf security system can be bypassed using XSS, thus the attacker doesn't need to know the cookie to exploit the xss vulnerability.

> To avoid cross site request forgery I
>   have added a random key in a hidden
>   field to the forms. This key is must
>   be returned in each POST request for
>   the request to be accepted.

For  instance, using XSS an attacker can execute JavaScript which can read any page on the domain using xmlhttprequest. Thus by using xmlhttprequest an attacker can read the XSRF token and then use it to forge the POST request.  This is because one property of XSS is that it allows for a break in the [Same Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest). As an example, [Here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7922) is a real world exploit that I wrote which does what i just explained.

The best way to prevent XSS is to convert nastily characters like `<>` into their corresponding html entities.  In PHP I recommend:

```
$var=htmlspeicalchars($var,ENT_QUOTES);
```

This will fix single quotes and double quotes so it can stop *most* xss. Even if the resulting sting is in a html tag.   For instance an attacker can't use this exploit if you replace quote marks. This is because the attacker has to break out of quotes in order to execute an "onload=".

```
$var="' onload='alert(document.cookie)'";
```

into this html:

```
print("<img src='http://HOST/img.php?=".$var."'>");
```

**HOWEVER**,  the specific case that you listed using a `<span>` tag is still potentially a problem because the attacker doesn't need quote marks! Your also going to have a xss vulnerability if you put  inside a `<script>` tag. Just be safe about where user input is being placed, there isn't a "catch all" or "silver bullet"  for all vulnerabilities.

The "XST" attack which leverages the HTTP "TRACE" method is not a realistic attack in practice. The reason why is that it is impossible for an attacker to force a web browser into making a "TRACE" http request.   Attackers can force the "GET" and "POST" methods using javascript or an `<img>` tag in the case of "GET",  but the rest of the HTTP header is off limits.  Keep in mind that TRACE is enabled by default in nearly all Apache systems,  if it was really hazardous it would be removed all together.  Many security testing tools like Nessus will throw an error if Apache supports TRACE,  it can also be disabled easily.

Comment: I assume OP wants to allow user authored html and css input to render. Application such yahoo mail or gmail that allow html email fall in this category. If not, then then ignore my answer and the rest of this comment (essentially agree with Michael).

If you want to allow user authored html and css html, encoding all input is not appropriate. E.g., an a href in input will be transformed to &lt;a. Whitelist tags and attribute names. Sanitize attribute values (e.g., href should not allow javascript). Same for CSS (sandbox).

Comment: Mar: You are right, we want to display html formatted userinput (some from e-mail, so we cant force users to use something like BB-code).

Comment: Michael: TRACE can indeed be disabled easily, that's already done. Your claim that TRACE using XHR is impossible is not right, try:

    xhr.open('trace', '/', false);

But converting html characters to entities and escaping quotes is not a viable solution because of the necessity to display userinput containing basic HTML.

Comment: @Tom, right but in order to use XHR you must be executing JavaScript in the same context as the domain.   Other wise this would be a violation of the Same Origin Policy. http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy_for_XMLHttpRequest  Its a moot point and thats why its still enabled on 99% of servers.   You **CAN** send GET and POST requests from any domain to any domain using JS and HTML,  and thats why XSRF is a still a serious problem.

Comment: @Tom, Further more html entries is the most common method of xss protection because unlike striptags(), the message is still human readable while also preventing more edge cases of xss. In order to make an omelet you gotta break some eggs, security is all about making software less useful.   On a side note,  TRACE is disabled on my servers because it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rook Could you please elaborate on `http://www.milw0rm.com/exploits/7922` ? (is it down?)

Comment: @user3529850 Link updated, it is an XSS payload that reads the CSRF token. I explained it completely.